# React Native - Why do we link libraries with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

For iOS. There's `react-native link`, then there's dragging a node module's `.xcodeproj` into the `Libraries` folder in Xcode AKA. manual linking.

I've seen some solutions where the node module, let's for the sake of  an example that I'm using `react-native-camera`, would be treated as a pod.

In this case, in my `Podfile`, I'd write: `pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'`.

Why would this be a considerable approach? What are the benefits, is it a killer solution instead of manually linking?